# Show that if $z_n \to z$ then $\exists M \in R $ such that $|z_n|\leq M\; \forall n \in N$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, proof-verification, limits-without-lhopital

Show that if $z_n \to z$ then $\exists M \in R $ such that $|z_n|\leq M\; \forall n \in N$

Let $z_n = x_n + \iota y_n$ and $z=x+\iota  y$

$z_n \to z$

$\rightarrow x_n \to x      $       and $y_n \to y$

because $\langle x_n \rangle$ and $\langle y_n \rangle$ are sequences of real numbers, $\exists M_1$ and $M_2$  such that $|x_n|\leq M_1$ and $|y_n|\leq M_2 \; \; \forall n \in N$

$|z_n|= |x_n + \iota y_n| \leq |x_n| + |y_n| \leq M_1 + M_2 = M \; \; forall n$

Is this proof correct?

My question is different, the sequence is in complex numbers and I have used the result directly quoted in the link

Comment: No, my sequence is of complex numbers and I have used the result quoted in that link

Comment: In any metric space, any convergent sequence is bounded. Your result (as the one posted) is only a special case of this. So, try proving this statement instead. Your proof is correct if you use the result on the link, but simplicity is not to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a duplicate but :

$z_n\to z$ to for $n\geq n_0$, $|z_n-z|\leq 1$, so by the inverse triangular identity of $|\cdot|$ in $\mathbb C$, $|z_n|\leq |z|+1$ for $n\geq n_0$.
So, $z_n\leq \max\{z_n|n\leq n_0\} + |z| + 1<\infty$ sor $(z_n)_n$is bounded.

As JustDroppedIn said, this is just a property of norms in normed vector spaces, or more generally, of metrics in metric spaces.